# How do OWIN Authentication providers work? How would I write a custom one?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, owin

I'm looking at the source code for `Microsoft.OWIN.Security.Google` and am a bit confused and overwhelmed at how many classes there are to do such a simple thing (redirect, get a cookie, check it).

Can anyone explain how the various components fit together

- Middleware
- Extensions
- etc

... so that I can write a custom provider

Answer (score 2):

After some google-ing and trying different ideas in debugger I ended up with "copy-paste-edit" :)

here is a brief resume of classes

**Extensions** - nothing special, a helper:

```
// instead of using
app.Use(typeof(CustomAuthenticationMiddleware), app, options);
// you can use
app.UseCustomAuthentication(options);
```

**Middlware** - methods are used to attach authentication to owin pipeline

**AuthenticationProvider** - As I understand, this could be overriden outside, to be able to change some logic without rewriting whole thing. Has 2 methods:

`Authenticated` - is called when handler finishes all authentication in `AuthenticationHandler.AuthenticateCoreAsync()`

`ReturnEndpoint` which is called in `AuthenticationHandler.InvokeAsync`, just before external authetication.

But it appeared absolutely useless, when I tried to customize existing providers (google, facebook,...)

**Handler** - here is all the OAUTH2 functionality.

`ApplyResponseChallengeAsync()` - generates AuthorizationEndpoint URL and redirects useragent to authorization server

`InvokeAsync()` - handles the get to RedirectEndpoint (/signin-google or whatever was set up on authorization server) and returns the user to the starting controller(or callback). It is doing a redirect with all needed cookies set up

AuthenticateCoreAsync() - does all server side calls to authorization server. Creates all `Identity.Claims` necessary to create appropriate cookies before